# Cannot connect to Remote Desktop with Windows Hello PIN

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

When I try to connect to an intranet machine, it only works if I specify domain credentials. When I use Windows Hello pin, it fails with this message:

```
An authentication error has occurred (Code: 0x8007013d)
Remote computer: theremotecomputername
```

Additional information:

- Client is running Win10 enterprise. I can use the Windows Hello PIN normally for login into client and for applications. Only RDP fails.
- Remote computer can be either Win10 enterprise or Win2016 server. Both fail.
- Client and remote are domain-joined and I am admin of these computers (I'm not domain admin).
- I can connect to remote with domain credentials, however any application that requires a PIN in the remote computer fails.

Comment: When you login to your client are you using a domain account with a Windows Hello PIN or are you using a Microsoft account with a Windows Hello pin?

Comment: Domain account. It's Windows Hello for Business. This used to work. Some update broke it, or something expired.

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate group policy "Use Windows Hello for Business certificates as smart card certificates".